# Not found 'locks' in sp_configure - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I can't find the 'locks' information in `sp_configure`.

I am using SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.5820.21).

I understand I should be able to find it on the 'Advanced' tab on the server properties, but is that normal? How can I bring up the 'locks' information in `sp_configure`?

Thank you for your answer..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `locks` option is an advanced one, and is not shown by `sp_configure` by default. In order to see it, you need to enable advanced options first:

```sql
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
go
reconfigure;
go
```

Then it will show up.

Comment: Hi Roger, 
thanks for the answer .. it works to display locks information ..